# Handling multiple return values in ANTLR

Tags: return-value, antlr

I have a simple rule in ANTLR:

```
title returns [ElementVector<Element> v]
@init{

    $v = new ElementVector<Element>() ;

}
    :   '[]'    
    |   '[' title_args {$v.add($title_args.ele);} (',' title_args {$v = $title_args.ele ;})* ']' 
    ;
```

with title_args being:

```
title_args returns [Element ele]
    :   author {$ele = new Element("author", $author.text); }
    |   location {$ele = new Element("location", $location.text); }
    ;
```

Trying to compile that I get confronted with a 127 error in the title rule: title_args is a non-unique reference.

I've followed the solution given to another similar question in this website ([How to deal with list return values in ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759028/how-to-deal-with-list-return-values-in-antlr)) however it only seems to work with lexical rules.

Is there a specific way to go around it ?

Thank you,
Christos

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 title_args in your expression, you need to alias them.  Try this:

```
|   '[' t1=title_args {$v.add($t1.ele);} (',' t2=title_args {$v = $t2.ele ;})* ']'
```

t1 and t2 are arbitrary aliases you can choose anything you want as long as they match up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your reusing the `title_args` var. Try changing one of those variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had the same problem.
You need to change one of the variable names; for example, do like the following:

```
title_args
title_args1
```

in your code instead of using title_args twice.

If title_args is a parser rule, then just create the same rule with the name title_args1.
So, basically there would be two rules with the same functionality.

Comment: This is a hack and bad advice.  The right answer is the one above, declare a variable name for each production using <var name>=<production>  and then reference that.